# Problema ao atribuir valores a um struct em C

Tags: c, struct, estrutura-de-dados

Olá, eu sei programar em outras linguagens mas sou iniciante em C e estou queimando a cuca fazendo um trabalho para a faculdade que pede pra armazenar informações de 10 veiculos em um array de structs. Nesse struct, as placas são definidas como XXX-YYYY (onde x são as letras e y os numeros) e para ter essa organização eu criei um struct separado para a placa e dentro do veículo eu uso um dado do tipo PLACA, porém, ao chamar o valor da placa, meu retorno para placa.letras é o dado completo ao inves de vir somente as letras, vem tudo e em placa.numeros vem somente os numeros. Segue o código.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>

// Struct Placa
typedef struct placa
{
  char letras[3];
  char numeros[4];
} PLACA;

// Struct Veiculo
typedef struct veiculo
{
  char marca[50];
  char modelo[50];
  int anofab;
  struct placa placa;
} VEICULO;
```

A seguir minhas funções:

```
void listarveiculos(VEICULO veiculos[])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    if (strlen((veiculos[i].modelo)) != 0)
    {
      printf("Marca: %s\n", veiculos[i].marca);
      printf("Modelo: %s\n", veiculos[i].modelo);
      printf("Ano de Fabricação: %s\n", veiculos[i].anofab);
      exibirplaca(veiculos[i].placa);
    }
  }
}

void exibirplaca(PLACA placa)
{
  char placaformatada[8] = placa.letras;
  strcat(placaformatada, "-");
  strcat(placaformatada, placa.numeros);

  strupr(placaformatada);

  printf("Placa: %s\n\n", placaformatada);
}
```

ao tentar compilar obtenho o seguinte erro:

```
veiculos.c: In function 'listarveiculos':
veiculos.c:55:7: warning: implicit declaration of function 'exibirplaca' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
       exibirplaca(veiculos[i].placa);
       ^~~~~~~~~~~
veiculos.c: At top level:
veiculos.c:60:6: warning: conflicting types for 'exibirplaca'
 void exibirplaca(PLACA placa)
      ^~~~~~~~~~~
veiculos.c:55:7: note: previous implicit declaration of 'exibirplaca' was here
       exibirplaca(veiculos[i].placa);
       ^~~~~~~~~~~
veiculos.c: In function 'exibirplaca':
veiculos.c:62:28: error: invalid initializer
   char placaformatada[8] = placa.letras;
                            ^~~~~
```

Já queimei a cuca aqui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> eu uso um dado do tipo PLACA, porém, ao chamar o valor da placa, meu retorno para placa.letras é o dado completo ao inves de vir somente as letras, vem tudo e em placa.numeros vem somente os numeros

Em C strings são null-terminated, tem um zero no fim. Para poder `%s` no `printf()` e funções de string.h precisaria ter um 0 entre as letras  e os números em cada placa, e um outro zero ao final.

Suas estruturas tem um nível a menos do que o prático: é mais conveniente ter `Veiculos` como uma coleção de `Veiculo`, cada `Veiculo` com sua `Placa`.

#### Veja um exemplo:

É só um esqueleto, mas deve ajudar a entender a notação nessa linguagem e o lance de mais um nível de encapsulamento para os dados, criando `Veiculos`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    char    letras[4];
    char    numeros[5];

}   Placa;

typedef struct
{
    char    marca[50];
    char    modelo[50];
    int     anofab;
    Placa   placa;

}   Veiculo;

typedef struct {
    int     N;
    Veiculo v[10]; // capacidade fixa: 10

}   Veiculos;

void listar_veiculos(Veiculos*);

int         main(void)
{
    srand(210820);
    Veiculo     um = { "Aston Martin", "DB5", 1964, (Placa){ "ABC", "1234" } };
    Veiculos    frota;
    frota.N = 0; // sem veiculos

    // cria uns
    while ( frota.N < 8 )
    {
        frota.v[frota.N] = um;
        // inventa novo numero para a placa
        sprintf( frota.v[frota.N].placa.numeros, "%04d", rand() % 10000 );
        frota.N += 1;
    };
    listar_veiculos(&frota);
    return 0;
}

void listar_veiculos(Veiculos* f)
{
    printf("%d veiculos no total\n", f->N);
    for (int i = 0; i < f->N; i++)
    {
        printf("    %s %s Ano %d Placa: %s-%s\n",
            f->v[i].marca,
            f->v[i].modelo,
            f->v[i].anofab,
            f->v[i].placa.letras,
            f->v[i].placa.numeros
            );
    };  // for()
};
```

Que mostra

```
8 veiculos no total
    Aston Martin DB5 Ano 1964 Placa: ABC-1539
    Aston Martin DB5 Ano 1964 Placa: ABC-2774
    Aston Martin DB5 Ano 1964 Placa: ABC-7665
    Aston Martin DB5 Ano 1964 Placa: ABC-1366
    Aston Martin DB5 Ano 1964 Placa: ABC-6816
    Aston Martin DB5 Ano 1964 Placa: ABC-3295
    Aston Martin DB5 Ano 1964 Placa: ABC-9245
    Aston Martin DB5 Ano 1964 Placa: ABC-9244
```

Tendo um *container* para o conjunto de carros é mais simples de escrever e controlar.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação e pelas sugestões. De fato, usar um container para os veículos facilitou muito a manipulação. Só tem uma coisa que eu não entendi direito: (Placa){ "ABC", "1234" } nessa parte, isso é uma forma de deixar explicito o tipo do valor?

Comment: Essa é uma constante do tipo `Placa` como `1964` é para o `anofab` que é `int`.  Assim não precisa de uma variável `Placa` em `main()`. Só um exemplo. E de todo modo o valor vai ser redefinido via `sprintf()` depois.